# In a Sub-Select, select Column from a Max-ID Row without ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Oracle 19c. I'm not allowed to have Sub-Selects with ORDER BY.

I need to get certain columns from a Max-ID row as a Sub-Select (because of a Hibernate Formula):

**Plans.java** PLANS_T Domain Object

```
@Formula(value="
(SELECT wf.last_changed_date 
 FROM plan_workflow_t wf 
 WHERE wf.plan_id = id and rownum = 1 order by id desc)
")
```

Is there a way to rewrite this without ORDER BY/rownum but keep it a Sub-Select?

I can't do `max(last_changed_date)`. The Max LastChangedDate can be on a different row than the latest row by ID; this means that the latest row by ID would have a NULL LastChangedDate, and that's what I have to return. So I need to grab specific columns (in this case `last_changed_date`) from the Max-ID row.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Hibernate so I can't tell whether any of these will actually help; try and see.

Just to know what date format is being used:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from plan_workflow_t order by plan_id;

   PLAN_ID LAST_CHANG
---------- ----------
         1 20.07.2020
         2 13.05.2020
         3 15.02.2018             --> you need this date value
```

The most straightforward query:

```
SQL> select a.last_changed_date
  2  from plan_workflow_t a
  3  where a.plan_id = (select max(b.plan_id) from plan_workflow_t b);

LAST_CHANG
----------
15.02.2018
```

Or, an analytic function, perhaps?

```
SQL> select max(x.retval) retval
  2  from (select first_value(a.last_changed_date) over (order by a.plan_id desc) retval
  3        from plan_workflow_t a
  4       ) x;

RETVAL
----------
15.02.2018

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, `...= (select max(b.plan_id) from plan_workflow_t b);` worked, thanks.